# is it possible to create a summation function with log n time complexity?

Tags: sum, big-o, recurrence

I have the following code:

```
def summation(numbers):
    """Given a list, returns the sum of the numbers in the list."""
    n = len(numbers)
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return numbers[0]
    middle = math.floor(n / 2)
    return summation(numbers[:middle]) + summation(numbers[middle:])
```

I'm wondering if it is possible for this function to have θ(log(n)) time complexity?
When creating recurrence relation and unrolling, I found it to be log n. But my intuition tells me that to sum a function you have to go over each element, which means it should be θ(n). Could someone please explain?

Comment: No, it will be linear as your intuition told you. The binary splitting is a bit confusing but although the "tree" will have the depth of log(n), the number of traversed "nodes" will be still n. Because as you said you need to visit each element to sum it up.

Comment: What @wohlstad said. The key is the last line: You are making the recursive call for both halves. If you called only for one half, then it would be log(n), just like in binary search. Intuitively, you are building up a tree of size n and depth log(n), but iterating through all n nodes.